# Can I store an Ini file in a Resources file?

Tags: c#, winforms, ini

I have a Windows Forms application, .Net Framework 4.6.1, and I want to store some DB connection data in an Ini file.

I then wanted to store it in the Resources file of the project (so I don't have to copy/paste the file in the Debug and Release folder manually, etc.) as a normal file, but when I tried to compile the program and read the Ini data with ini-parser, the following exception showed up: `System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid characters in path access'`.

I'm using `Properties.Resources` where I read the Ini file, so I guessed there would be no problem with the path. Could it be a problem with the Ini file itself?

The content of the Ini file is the following:

```
[Db]
host = (anIP)
port = (aPort)
db = (aDbName)
user = (aDbUser)
password = (aDbUserPwd)
```

And my method for reading the data:

```cs
public static void ParseIniData()
{
    var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
    IniData data = parser.ReadFile(Properties.Resources.dbc);

    mysqlHost = data["Db"]["host"];
    mysqlPort = data["Db"]["port"];
    mysqlDb = data["Db"]["db"];
    mysqlUser = data["Db"]["user"];
    mysqlPwd = data["Db"]["password"];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply add the file to your project and set the "Copy to Output Directory" property for the ini accordingly?

Comment: Is this the ini-parser from https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser? To get the contents of the INI file contents, you have to use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` and the `StreamIniDataParser`.

Comment: @Ralf I didn't event thing about that... makes much more sense really. Thank you, and sorry!

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes it is! Thank you a lot! I should have checked the docs better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally could do it using what @KlausGütter told me in the comments (thanks!).

Instead of using the `FileIniDataParser` you have to use the `StreamIniDataParser`, and get the Stream with `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`.

I found this a bit tricky, because using this method you need to set the `Build Action` in the file you want to read to `Embedded Resource`. 
This file is then added as an embedded resource in compile time and you can retrieve its stream.

So my method ended up the following way:

```cs
public static void ParseIniData()
{
    var parser = new StreamIniDataParser();
    dbcReader = new StreamReader(_Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("NewsEditor.Resources.dbc.ini"));

    IniData data = parser.ReadData(dbcReader);

    mysqlHost = data["Db"]["host"];
    mysqlPort = data["Db"]["port"];
    mysqlDb = data["Db"]["db"];
    mysqlUser = data["Db"]["user"];
    mysqlPwd = data["Db"]["password"];
}
```

where `_Assembly` is a private static attribute: `private static Assembly _Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();`. This gets you the assembly that's being executed when running the code (you could also use this code directly in the method, but I used the Assembly on another method in my class, so I decided to set an attribute... DRY I guess).